# jquery code working fine, but other radio button interferring with its working

Tags: javascript, jquery

here are two jquery codes

code 1

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("div.imgDisp").hide();
    $('[id="' + $(":radio:checked").val()+'"]').show();
    $(":radio").click(function() {      
        $("div.imgDisp").fadeOut('slow');
        $('[id="' + $(this).val()+'"]').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

This code hides the divs on selecting a radio button
check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/qudT2/3/

in this fiddle you can see a set of radios under name = "type". All works well till here..

there are other set of radio buttons as well under different names.. now the problem is that when i click any of those radio buttons under diffrent names, and although they are not related anyway to this fiddle code clicking them nullify the effect of this fiddle and the desired effect of this fiddle just vanishes.
i.e. if i click on any other radio button other then those shown in fiddle, they make the displayed result hide, while the result in fiddle shall stay on screen. I m surprised..

same problem is with another jquery code i have used to show/hide a textfiled.. [I M OMITTING ANOTHER CODE CUZ THE PROBLEM IS SAME WITH THAT CODE ALSO]

what could be wrong guys? thanks in advance..

Comment: You say "here are two jquery codes" but you only include "code 1" in your question. Did you forget to include "code 2"?

Comment: `$(":radio[name=type]").click(function() {`should work

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg i ve update the reason of not entering the second code..

Comment: nothing to your problem, but `id`s have to be unique, two elements should not have the same id.

Comment: @t.niese if i use unique id's then how can i get the desired output? since i need to hide multiple divs with same "some sort of value (here hence i chose same id's)". I already am aware of that id shall be unique.. but this code with same id's is working..

Comment: @Sumit by not using `id`s but `class`es. something like `imgDisp-100` or `imgDisp-300` and then search for `$(".imgDisp-"+$(this).val())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem here is you are calling click event for all radio i.e `$(":radio").click(function() {  ..` specify thhe click event to those radios only whose `name="type"`..

```
$('input[name="type"]:radio').click(function() {.... });
```

try this

```
$('input[name="type"]:radio').click(function() {
    $("div.imgDisp").fadeOut('slow');
    $('[id="' + $(this).val()+'"]').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

this will only call the click event for input whose name="type" and radio .

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/qudT2/4/)

Comment: I would also replace `$('[id="' + $(this).val()+'"]')` with `$('#' + $(this).val())`, i.e. use the normal jQuery "by id" selector.

Comment: it is not working.. it is again hiding on clicking other fields :(

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg can u update the same in this fiddle? cuz the solution provided by bipen is not working and the problem is as it is fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/qudT2/4/

Comment: @Peter Herdenborg  this does not work, because the id's are not unique, there are elements with the same `id`

Comment: @t.niese You are right! Though duplicate IDs are really invalid and should probably be avoided rather than "hacking" the id selector.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg how can then i check the value for the same if i remove id's

Comment: @bipen it worked automatically... surprising computer.. thanks

Comment: @Sumit This is with slight modification to bipen's solution http://jsfiddle.net/V73km/

Comment: @Sumit I would use a class instead. Also, I think "100", i.e. all numbers, is invalid both as an ID and as a class name. `<div class="c100">...</div>` would do the trick for example, if you change your selector to `$('.c' + $(this).val())`

Comment: thank u guys... @PeterHerdenborg ... i was away for a while and i see 9 comments... anyways all of your solutions is better,readable .. :)

Comment: Sorry for flooding your answer @bipen :)

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik what advantage your fiddle holds??

Comment: actually there is no changes in it..both are same performance wise..since even he is using the same attribute selector `input[class="type"]` in which i am using `input[name="type"]`... so performance wise there is no chnages at all...but to use his you have to add class again to input which is unneccessary and waste of time....

Comment: @bipen It was because "other" also had the same "type" as the other radio buttons. So your code was running even for the "other" radio button. In my modification it would only run for the radio buttons that OP wanted, while keeping the same type for all radio buttons.